# PostFactory does not exist in generated Interceptor in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, bug, factory, post

> any solution for this bug

```
 [RuntimeException]                                                           
  Class Vendor\Company\Model\PostFactory does not exist in [Vendor\Company\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor]
```

> 1. block post.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Company\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context;

class Campaign extends Template
{
    public function __construct(Context $context,array $data = [])
    {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }
    public function getFormAction()
        {
        return $this->getUrl('vendor/index/submit', ['_secure' => true]);  
    }
}
```

> 2 model/resourceModel/post.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Company\Model\ResourceModel;

class Submit extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb
{
    
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Context $context
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
    
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('vendor_company', 'campaign_id');
    }
    
}
```

> 3. Controller post.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Company\Controller\Index;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $_pageFactory;

    protected $_postFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $pageFactory,
        \Vendor\Company\Model\PostFactory $postFactory
        )
    {
        $this->_pageFactory = $pageFactory;
        $this->_postFactory = $postFactory;
        return parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $post = $this->_postFactory->create();
        $collection = $post->getCollection();
        foreach($collection as $item){
            echo "<pre>";
            print_r($item->getData());
            echo "</pre>";
        }
        exit();
        return $this->_pageFactory->create();
    }
}
```

> 4. Model post.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Company\Model;

class Submit extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel implements \Magento\Framework\DataObject\IdentityInterface
{
    const CACHE_TAG = 'vendor_company';

    protected $_cacheTag = 'vendor_company';

    protected $_eventPrefix = 'vendor_company';

    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('Vendor\Company\Model\ResourceModel\Submit');
    }

    public function getIdentities()
    {
        return [self::CACHE_TAG . '_' . $this->getId()];
    }

    public function getDefaultValues()
    {
        $values = [];

        return $values;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please share that code so that i can give you exact solution

Comment: sure i will show my code

Comment: have you check by remove generated and var/cache folder ?

Comment: i have checked generated and var/cache folder

Comment: have you check permission of generated and var , if not than set it to 777

Comment: Access permission is already given

Comment: Hey your model file classs name is wrong model/resourceModel/post.php , right now it's Submit .but it should be Post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Vendor\Company\Model\PostFactory` Class is injected at `Vendor\Company\Controller\Index\Index` (in the constructor) and from there the error occurs.

If you have `Vendor\Company\Model\Post` Class then during **di *(Dependency Injection)* compilation** `Vendor\Company\Model\PostFactory` should automatically be created.

There might be two reason the issue happens:

- `Vendor\Company\Model\Post` does not exit.
- Or Dependency Injection does not know about the file yet.

  - Delete all files& folder from `generate/code`, `generate/metadata` and run:

```
   php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

You have two options regarding `Vendor/Company/Model/Post`:

- If `Vendor\Company\Model\Post`  does not exits then you have to remove `Vendor\Company\Model\PostFactory` from `Vendor\Company\Controller\Index\Index` constructor.
- Or create new `Vendor\Company\Model\Post` and run the di compilation.

*(Depends on your requirements which is best)*

Comment: Vendor\Company\Model\Post it is existed in my module